# Is this plant beyond saving?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health

My company recently moved offices and we adopted some plants left by the previous inhabitants. While many were in bad shape, all but one are recovering quite well and I am not sure what to do with this one. It previously lived in a hallway where there is never any sunlight and is now in an office with daylight. We water it weekly. Does it need more/less water? More/less light? A bigger pot? Some possibility to climb? I am absolutely clueless about plants and would hate to see this wonderful creature die due to my / the previous owners lack of care.

[image: Full view of plant]
[image: Only remaining healthy leaf]

(The dark spots on the images are from my camera, not on the wall/plant)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is worth a try. I would cut down all the upper branches, keep the one with the lower leaf, and possibly one with the upper leaf. You could also take the portion with the upper leaf, and give it a bit of rooting compound and try to root that in a new pot/medium. Any branches that have new leaves appearing might be worth saving, but the less energy that a healing plant has to put into feeding leaves, etc. the better.

If you have anything like Super-Thrive, give the plant just a tiny bit. It might help. A new layer of compost might also help. I have managed to pull off one to two plants like this that I neglected or forgot to pot after getting them on clearance. There is no guarantee it will survive though.

It is hard to tell, but the soil does appear wet, so that is good. Keeping the soil moist, but not too wet is good while it is trying to survive.

Comment: As long as there is virtually no photosynthetic growth I'd certainly be very careful with watering.  Allow that plant to dry between waterings.  I'd pop this plant out of the pot and check the roots.  They will likely be as desiccated like the top of the plant.  Get rid of the two pot gig for sure!   I'd also add fresh potting soil and repot in the same pot.  Cut that plant way down like Srihari discussed.  Do not fertilize until you've got lots of new growth happening. Super Thrive or a bit of fish fertilizer would be fine.  less is more